# codeigniter mp3 upload not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload, mp3

Trying to upload mp3s via a form using Codeignitor framework. My allowed types are mp3|wav. 
Wav files upload fine. Mp3s do not upload. Some people with this problem have added more meme types to memes.php. I have tried this to no avail.

Here is my controller code (again, works fine with wavs)

```
$this->load->model('songshare/Songmodel');
    $this->Songmodel->songupload($data);
    //upload data

    $config['upload_path'] = realpath(APPPATH.'../uploads/');
    $config['max_size']    = '0';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'mp3|wav';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);


    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {
        $data = array('msg' => $this->upload->display_errors());

    } else { //else, set the success message
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                    $field = 'userfile';                        
                    var_dump($_FILES[$field]['type']);
    }
```

If I upload a mp3 and have the vardump in the IF, it returns -
string '' (length=0)

If I upload a wav and have the vardump in the ELSE, it returns - 
string 'audio/x-wav' (length=11)

I am stumped quite frankly. Any idea what is going on here?

Thanks!

Comment: print_r($data) in IF check whats msg is coming

Comment: Ah, I just saw this...somehow I missed this comment earlier. So, it is telling me that "The uploaded file exceeds the maximum allowed size in your PHP configuration file."  I have changed the limit in PHP.ini to no avail. Is there a different file I should be doing this in?

Comment: Nevermind! Had to restart server! Working now, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I had not increased the file size to large enough. Changed max file size allow in php.ini.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to add more content-type to mime file and check  Or [check this](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/75310/) ,

```
‘mp3‘=>  array(‘audio/mpeg’,‘audio/mpeg3’,‘audio/mpg’,‘audio/x-mpeg’,‘audio/mp3’,‘application/force-download’,‘application/octet-stream’),
```

Comment: Yeah, I had seen that same page before going on here. Adding more mime types did not work for me. Someone said to do this...  $_FILES['user_file']['type'] = str_replace('\"' , '' , $_FILES['user_file']['type'] );

$_FILES['user_file']['type'] = str_replace('"' , '' , $_FILES['user_file']['type'] );                                                                  I put that in my function in the controller and changed user_file to my userfile (without the underscore like I have in my function)...still not working.

Comment: I am not getting an error, just an empty string...is there some way I can check for more info to see what is happening? Really need this to work ASAP. I have tried other things people have posted on forums..can't find much. Mostly people seem to have the mime problem but like I said, that didn't work.